# MapBox how to create MarkerCluster

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I try to switch from google maps to mapbox but I don't know how to do some of the things that can be done in GMap, currently I need to make my points inside clusters but all the example of mapbox gl js use geojson source, I want to cluster points created like that :

```
var myVar = new mapboxgl.Marker()
.setLngLat([lng, lat])
.addTo(map);'
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Right now clustering is only supported on GeoJSON sources see https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4491

Comment: Thanks this is more complicated than google maps ^^'